# Connect PHP socket to SFML

Tags: php, c++, tcp, sfml

I need to connect a PHP client to my server which is running from SFML Network library. I can connect to it with Android TCP, but in PHP, I get weird stuff happening, look at the pictures below:

[image: simple server]

[image: php client]

The weirdness I get once I load the php page:

[image: php page]

As said before, I can connect perfectly fine with Android, and send whatever I want, and the server will respond with "New Connection" and "Client sent whatever". I don't know if it has to do with php formating or anything? I've been stuck for a long time and can't find anything about it. If you need any other information or code I can send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an array and you print it, the array decays into a pointer which is what gets printed. `std::string[100]` will not fix your problem, in fact it's not what you want. Data over the network is sent in bytes so you want to capture those as a `char[100]`. once you have received the data into your array, make sure you do `message[size] = '\0'` which null terminates your char array and lets you safely use it as a string which can be done with `std::string(message, size)`.

Comment: I'm not using sf:: Packet, as I said this works fine when android connects with the android sockets. I'm sending a string from Android and the server revieves it, and puts it into a char[] and can read it fine. Maybe there's a way in PHP to convert the php string into a c string which is what I did in android before sending

Comment: I see that my code shows that I'm trying to get a string directly not a char[] array, but that was just a test, I have used char[] not std:: string